# MERGE related nodes in Neo4j

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I have a geohash graph with pickup and drop off nodes .

The end nodes(dropoff) can be repeated for different trips with different start nodes (pickup)
[image: not merged]

I need to merge this end nodes.
[image: merged]

This is what i have tried

```
MATCH (x:HashNode), (y:HashNode)
WHERE x.dropoff=y.dropoff
call apoc.refactor.mergeNodes([x,y]) YIELD node
RETURN node
```

But i get an error :

```
Neo.ClientError.Procedure.ProcedureCallFailed: Failed to invoke procedure `apoc.refactor.mergeNodes`: Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
```

any help ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that this query:

```
MATCH (x:HashNode), (y:HashNode)
WHERE x.dropoff=y.dropoff
```

produces all combinations of nodes with the same property. And for two nodes it will return:

```
X Y
Y X
X X
Y Y
```

And when the first pair is merged, when the queue for the next one comes up - these nodes will no longer be, and this will cause an error.

So you need to collect the nodes once. For example:

```
MATCH (x:HashNode)
WITH DISTINCT x.dropoff AS dropoffValue
MATCH (x:HashNode) WHERE x.dropoff = dropoffValue
WITH dropoffValue, collect(x) AS nds
CALL apoc.refactor.mergeNodes(nds) YIELD node
RETURN node
```